# Subsetting a dataset based on TRUE, FALSE logical vector

Tags: for-loop, undefined, error-messages-for

When running my forloop function, I came across the following error message: "Error in `[.data.frame`(returns, i:(i + 60), c(FALSE, ESGscores_logical)) : undefined columns selected". I have tried many different alterations but nothing seems to be working.
The error arises in the "returns_subset", where I would like to filter the correct 61 months and stocks in the 80%.
I have previously built the ESGscores_subset with all of the ESG scores in one year.
And then created the ESGscores_logical dataset with marking TRUE when the stock is in the higher 80%.

Here is my data:

as.data.frame(ESGscores)

| year | Stock A | Stock B | Stock C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 33 | 45 |
| 2 | 40 | 23 | 55 |
| 3 | 45 | 45 | 44 |
| 4 | 55 | 50 | 45 |

as.data.frame(returns)

| year | Month | Stock A | Stock B | Stock C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.033 | 0.045 | 0.066 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.0023 | 0.0055 | 0.07 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.035 | 0.00344 | 0.033 |
| 1 | 4 | 0.004 | 0.005 | 0.04 |

ESGscores_subset

| year | Month | Stock A | Stock B | Stock C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.033 | 0.045 | 0.066 |

ESGscores_logical

| Stock A | Stock B | Stock C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |

Here is my code:

```
        for(i in 1:60) {
         year <- returns[i+60,"Year"]
  
          ESGscores_subset <- ESGscores[ESGscores$year == year-1, 2:411] 
          ESGscores_logical <- as.numeric(ESGscores_subset) >= 
            as.numeric(quantile(ESGscores_subset, 0.8))
          returns_subset <- returns[i:(i+60), c(FALSE, ESGscores_logical)] 
         }
```

I am really stuck, your help would be much appreciated!